# How to iterate over JSON object in JavaScript and create table with it?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a JSON with this structure:

```
diferencias = {
    "1": {
      "1": 543.0, 
      "0": 542.0
    }, 
    "2": {
      "0 1": 0.3333333333333333
    }
}
```

I need to obtain a table with outer keys as columns.

I wrote the following code:

```
$("#pinchetabla").empty()
    var tr = ""
    for (d in diferencias) {
        var r = ''
        for (dd in d) {
            //console.log(dd)
            r += '<tr>' + 'f[' + diferencias.dd + ']=' + diferencias.d.dd + '</tr>'
        }
        tr += r
    }

    var table = "<table id='resultados' class='table table-condensed'>" + tr + "</table>"
$("#pinchetabla").append(table)
```

I've got following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fQ9Py/)

Where `pinchetabla` is a `div`. However I can't even properly access the JSON keys and values.  What am I missing?

Comment: Instead of `for(dd in d)` your need `for (dd in diferencias[d])` for a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of problems.

1. When you iterate a dictionary in javascript it returns the keys. So your inner iteration loop should be `for(dd in diferencias[d])`
2. You need `<td>` tags as well.
3. You need to instantiate `var tr` before you use it (`tr += r`)

http://jsfiddle.net/fQ9Py/1/

Comment: Thanks! Anny suggest to make table better, I actually would like to obtain a column for each outer key and its inner keys as subcolumns inside each. I'd thank you soo much

Comment: I kind of assumed you were just using the table to get a feel for the iteration. Although a bit ugly, this edit http://jsfiddle.net/fQ9Py/2/ shows how to use `<td rowspan=x>` to group your rows by category. You could also create entire tables nested instead of just using rowspan, depends on what you want/need.

Answer (score 3):

When you access properties with [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Dot_notation), like this `object.propertyname`, JavaScript will look for `propertyname` in the `object`. In your case, `d` and `dd` are mere keys in the `object`, but JavaScript will be looking for them in the `diferencias` and fails to find them.

In order to access the properties dynamically, you have to use [subscript/bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation), like this

```
r += '<tr>' + 'f[' + d + ']=' + diferencias[d][dd] + '</tr>';
```

Also the for loop should be like this

```
for (dd in diferencias[d]) {
```

Your table creation code can be fixed like this

```
var tr = "";
for (d in diferencias) {
    var r = '<tr>';
    for (dd in diferencias[d]) {
        r += '<td>' + 'f[' + d + ']=' + diferencias[d][dd] + '</td>';
    }
    tr += r + '</tr>';
}
```